# Find shortest path between two arbitrary points on a network that's has disconnected edges/ways

Tags: pgrouting, routing

I have pre-defined bus routes as directed edges and they're all loops starting and ending on the same point.
Sometimes they form a polygon with no intersections with other bus loops and sometimes it intersects with other loops or even with itself.

I'm creating a web application that allows users to put `origin` and `destination` markers anywhere on a map (leafletjs) and route from A(origin) to B(dest) using only the bus routes. Anything in between the routes are considered walkable.

Sample graph:
[image]

**How do I use pgrouting to route from PointA -> edge#3 -> edge#4 -> PointB when they're disconnected?**

Please take note that the bus loops don't have "bus stops" so users can basically ride/stop anywhere like a taxi -- so edges would have to be split when routing.

What I can do so far:

1. Draw line `lineB` from B to nearest edge `edgeX` (edge/route #1 on drawing below), save `lineB` geom to temp table
2. Draw line `lineA` from A to same edge above, save `lineA` geom to temp table
3. Save `edgeX` to temp table
4. pgr_nodenetwork() `temp` table
5. pgr_createtopology() on `temp_noded`
6. pgr_dijkstra() which returns the path below

pgr_dijkstra():
[image]

Edit:

- there's no consideration for time/schedule (only distance is considered)
- edges/ways have `reverse_cost`
- I want to consider or increase cost of transferring routes so less transfers are preferred
- I also want to get maybe 2 or 3 suggested itineraries like `order by agg_cost ASC` of different routes calculated (which I don't know how to implement yet)